# How to insert a component into Strapi content-type property via the query api programmatically?

Tags: strapi

I am using Strapi `"@strapi/strapi": "4.11.3",`

I have created a `Post` content-type in Strapi (schema here https://github.com/kristijorgji/strapi-blog-cms/blob/main/src/api/post/content-types/post/schema.json) which includes the component `seo` from the plugin
https://market.strapi.io/plugins/@strapi-plugin-seo

I am seeding some posts for development purpose in my public repo https://github.com/kristijorgji/strapi-blog-cms but cannot fill the `seo` field of the post no matter what I try...

According to their documentations what I am trying should have worked fine https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/entity-service/components-dynamic-zones#creation but it is not the case!
The component is not created and filled inside the post and neither do I get any error.... Please note, the post is created but `seo` is just null/empty.

I am trying in `seed-test-data.ts` the code as below

```
 await strapi.db.query("api::post.post").create({
      data:
        {
          title: 'my first post',
          content: `#this is my first post and it is seeded by the strapi api in the bootstrap file
                    <p>It is using nested html inside markup as well</p>`,
          slug: 'my-first-post',
          categories: {
            connect: [3],
          },
          tags: {
            connect: [1],
          },
          seo: { metaDescription: 'example', }
          publishedAt: new Date(),
          createdBy: 1,
          updatedBy: 1,
        },
    });
```

and it creates the post fine but without the `seo` field filled.

Any input please?

Comment: You need entity service, db query doesn’t do components.

Comment: Db.query get data, entityService update

Comment: @antokhio thanks I tried that before posting here but got error `TypeError: strapi.entityService.create(...).create is not a function
`

Comment: Also can you please comment your answer with example code. Maybe you meant something else

Comment: Use entity service for create or update, db query for querying (find, findMany)

Comment: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/entity-service/crud#create

Comment: If you are on ts you might need @ts-expect-error, there are  incorrect types present quite often

Comment: I think the error that I pasted above is `runtime error` when I run `yarn develop` and tried to execute that code. I don't think was the tslint or compilation error

Comment: Start out by commenting out parts of the request until it works, and then add features.

Comment: Also can recommend a nice vid https://youtu.be/kohbOP6Eh9I

Comment: Guess the problem is connect, you prolly want pass an array with [{id},{id}] instead of connect…

Comment: @antokhio the connect works fine. The relationships are added fine and has nothing to do with `seo`. Only `seo` is not beiing innserted,  other fiields including categories that use connect inserrt fine

Comment: Well it’s not going to work with db.query

Comment: It’s explicitly written in db.query vs entity service, https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/query-engine

Comment: What i mean, is component not going to work with db.query

Comment: Yes, I also tried what you suggested with  `entityService.create` and did not work as I pasted above the error..

Comment: Yes, so to make components work you have to use entityService, so just remove the `categories` and `tags` from request temporarily and see if it works...